# jquery timeout failing in chrome after a while

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, settimeout

so i have this script that is simply fading p tags in and out and cycling through them. For some reason if i leave the page open for awhile, they stop fading out and just start stacking on  top of eachother. It takes awhile for it to happen and I think it only happens in chrome.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   var current_quote = 0,
   fade_interval = null,
   num_quotes = $("#quotes p").length;

  // Fade in the first quote.
   $("#quote0").fadeIn(2500);

  // Schedule for the inital fade out.
  setTimeout(fadeQuotes, 6000);

  function fadeQuotes() {
    // Fade out the current quote.
    $("#quote" + current_quote).fadeOut(2500, function() {
    // Fade in the next quote.
    current_quote = (current_quote + 1) 
    if(current_quote+1 > num_quotes)
    {
        current_quote=0;
    }
    current_quote = current_quote % num_quotes;
    $("#quote" + current_quote).fadeIn(2500);
    });


    // Set the fading interval, if it's not already set.
    if (fade_interval == null) {
      fade_interval = setInterval(fadeQuotes, 13010);
    }
  }


});
```

Comment: The problem is - Chrome's V8 engine freezes javascript when you switch tabs. When you go back, it runs it in super fast mode. That messes up the display. I'm looking for a solution for this as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome sets timeout min to 1 second when page is in hidden tab. It's a bit weird.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the solution however some redundancies in your code may be causing a problem. Try this out...

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wdm954/beQxv/4/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // rotate quotes
    $(function() {
        var current_quote = 0;        
        $("#quote" + current_quote).fadeIn(2500);
        setInterval(function() {
            $("#quote" + current_quote).fadeOut(2500, function() {
                current_quote++;
                if (current_quote + 1 > $("#quotes p").length) current_quote = 0;
                $("#quote" + current_quote).fadeIn(2500);
            });
        }, 5000);
    });

}); //end doc ready
```

Comment: So even if I run your jsfiddle in chrome I see the same problem. Set the interval to 1 second and see

Comment: If your fadeIn is 2500 and your fadeOut is 2500 then your interval has to be at least 5000.